# External display lag on laptop extended desktop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

When I connect an external display to my laptop and extend my desktop, the external display will have a horrible update rate, to the point where I can't watch a movie or similar, since it becomes choppy.

The kicker is, this only happens when I choose to extend my desktop.
If I clone my desktop, both the external and built-in monitor work flawlessly.

I thought it may be the 4k resolution of my TV, vs the 1080p of my built-in, but if I go superresolution and set my built-in to 4k, the external monitor still works perfectly when cloned, but just as horrible when running extended.

I have tried with 2 different TV's 
I have tried with 3 different HDMI cables (2 passive, 1 active)

My laptop is a Lenovo Legion y530

Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this?

Comment: Another potential reason may be a buggy hardware acceleration on the secondary monitor (when cloned there is no secondary monitor). What GPU(s) are inside your laptop?

Comment: It has a Gtx 1050,   as well as Intel UHD graphics 630 in the cpu